# finding div height problem and changing margins commensurately

Tags: jquery, html, css

The various content DIVs show up in a slideshow style (I'm using [Malsup's Cycle plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)) a single one at a time, but have differing heights (individually, and at different times the largest height may be different). The `news` div has the height of the highest content DIV. I would like to center the content DIVs vertically within the `news` DIV. Is there a simple way to do this with CSS? Or should I use jquery to calculate the height of `newsWrapper`, subtract the `newsNav` heights, and `news` from it, halve that and then add it as `margin-top` for each of the content DIVs?

```
<div id="newsWrapper">
  <div id="newsNavTop">
  </div>
  <div id="news">
    <div>Content1</div>
    <div>Content2</div>
    <div>Content etc...</div>
  </div>
  <div id="newsNavBottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, _commensurately_... it's been far too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Or should I use jquery to calculate the height of newsWrapper, subtract the newsNav heights, and news from it, halve that and then add it as margin-top for each of the content DIVs?"

This.  Padding-top works too.

Answer (score 0):

you can try displaying this as table.

```
#news {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#news > div {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/seler/P23DJ/

it wont work in ie lte 7

Comment: But... it's not a table. Isn't that semantically inappropriate?

Comment: @aslum it is what W3C suggests to do in layouts.